# Need help translating text in my ts files

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Hey guys I am having trouble translating text in ts files like alerts and pops ups using ng-2 translate. I am already done translating HTML and that was very straightforward but i am stuck now, Let's say for example, my code is this:

```
showAlert() {
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
title: 'Confirmed',
subTitle: this.ride.type == "rider" ? 'Your ride request has been created.' : 'Your ride offer has been created.',
buttons: [{
text: 'Ok',
handler: () => {
alert.dismiss()
.then(()=>{
this.navCtrl.pop();
})
return false;
}
}]
});
alert.present();
}

}
```

How can I translate the title and subtitle? I already have keys and the corresponding translated text in the json files but i dont know how to syntactically do it here. In the html files it was just {{KEY | translate}} but not sure what its gonna be here. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use TranslateService.
You have two methods: instant and get.
Personally i alway use instant because i'm 100% sure that my translate file is loaded.
I wrote an example with get but it can be wrong (not tested).

```
import { TranslateService } from "ng2-translate";

constructor(
        protected translateService: TranslateService
) {
}

/* instant(key: string|Array<string>, interpolateParams?: Object): string|Object: Gets the instant translated value of a key (or an array of keys). /!\ This method is synchronous and the default file loader is asynchronous. You are responsible for knowing when your translations have been loaded and it is safe to use this method. If you are not sure then you should use the get method instead. */
showAlert() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: this.translateService.instant('KEY'),
        subTitle: this.ride.type == "rider" ? this.translateService.instant('KEY2') : this.translateService.instant('KEY3')
    });
}

/* otherwise */
showAlert() {
    this.translateService.get('KEY')
    .flatMap((trad) => {
        let key;
        if (this.ride.type == "rider") {
            key = 'KEY2';
        } else {
            key = 'KEY3';
        }
        return this.translateService.get(key).map((trad2) => {
                    return { trad: trad, trad2: trad2 };
                });
    })
    .subscribe((trads: { trad: string, trad2: string }) => {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: this.translateService.instant(trads.trad),
            subTitle: trads.trad2
        });
    }, 
    (error) => {
        // ERROR HERE (SUBSCRIBE NOT CALLED)
    });
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the **TranslateService** in your controller and then use the **get** method to get the translated string.

```
get(key: string|Array<string>, interpolateParams?: Object): Observable<string|Object>
```

You can see the method in the component to get the value. Keep in mind though that it returns an observable not the translated value directly.